# How to return the maximum and minimum values for specific ID SQL

Tags: sql, relational-database

Given the following SQL tables: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eUZs.jpg. For each specific ID_t I need to return the MAX() and MIN() value of Cena_c(total price) column of a given ID_t.

```
| ID_t | Nazwa |
| ---- | ----- |
| 1    | T1    |
| 2    | T2    |
| 3    | T3    |
| 4    | T4    |
| 5    | T5    |
| 6    | T6    |
| 7    | T7    |
```

```
| ID   | ID_t | Ilosc | Cena_j | Cena_c | ID_p |
| ---- | ---- | ----- | ------ | ------ | ---- |
| 100  | 1    | 1     | 10     | 10     | 1    |
| 101  | 2    | 3     | 20     | 60     | 2    |
| 102  | 4    | 5     | 10     | 50     | 7    |
| 103  | 2    | 2     | 20     | 40     | 5    |
| 104  | 5    | 1     | 30     | 30     | 5    |
| 105  | 7    | 6     | 80     | 480    | 1    |
| 106  | 6    | 7     | 15     | 105    | 2    |
| 107  | 6    | 5     | 15     | 75     | 1    |
| 108  | 3    | 3     | 25     | 75     | 7    |
| 109  | 7    | 1     | 80     | 80     | 5    |
| 110  | 4    | 1     | 10     | 10     | 2    |
| 111  | 2    | 9     | 20     | 180    | 2    |
```

Based on provided tables the correct result should look like this:

```
| ID_t  | Cena_c_max | Cena_c_min |
| ----- | ---------- | ---------- |
| T1    | 10         | 10         |
| T2    | 180        | 60         |
| T3    | 75         | 75         |
| T4    | 50         | 10         |
| T5    | 30         | 30         |
| T6    | 105        | 75         |
| T7    | 480        | 80         |
```

Is this even possible?
I haven't found anything yet that I could use to implement my solution.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please show what you tried, research is expected. See [ask], other [help] links, hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. Stop trying to code your overall goal & explain what you expected instead from the given code & why.

Comment: @philipxy Well I do not tryhard this much. I wish i could just delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT concat('T',ID_t), max(Cena_c) as Cena_c_max, min(Cena_c) as Cena_c_min
FROM table
GROUP BY ID_t`

Comment: What a simple soulution! Perhaps I should learn about GROUP BY. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Better is to solve it with joins of tables, because it will be avoided in the future if the prefix T is changed to another letter.

Hardcoding should be avoided.

```
select b.nazva as "Nazva", max(a.cena.c) as "Cena_c_max", min(a.cena.c) as "Cena_c_min"
from table1 as a
left join table2 as b on (
    a.id_t = b.id_t
)
group by id_t
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26117249)

Comment: Thank you for your advice, i am new on the platform and still learning the system. :)